# How to prove that these components of the Riemann tensor are equal?

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors

I have to prove some properties of the curvature in a bidimensional manifold, and doing so I noticed that I needed to calculate the relations between some components of the Ricci tensor
$$
R_{kq} = R^i_{kiq}
$$
By doing some calculations on the general expression of the Riemann tensor and using the symmetry under the swap of the last two covariant indices, I obtained the relations
$$
R^i_{iii} = 0\ , \quad R^1_{112} = R^1_{211} = 0 \quad\text{and}\quad R^2_{122} = R^2_{221} = 0
$$
So I am left with two more components of the Riemann tensor, which I know they must fulfil the following
$$
R^1_{212} = R^2_{121} \ne 0
$$
because the Riemann tensor only has one non-zero independent component in a bidimensional manifold. However, I would like to prove this last relation explicitely, i.e., not using symmetry properties of the indices. I tried to write those two components as functions of the Christoffel symbols, but I am not able to see any relation between them. Any idea?